# Cordova-plugin-printer crashing Ionic2 app

Tags: printing, crash, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to test printing functionality in an app. Am using katzer/cordova-plugin-printer.
I created a button that calls the printer, below is the code I wrote, not sure if its correct:

```
print(){
  Printer.isAvailable().then(
    ()=>{
      Printer.print("<h2>This is just a sample!</h2>").then(
        ()=>alert('Printing successfull'),
        ()=>{alert('Unable to print')}
      );
    }, 
    (reason)=>{
      alert('no printer found');
      alert(reason)
    });
```

}

I am using an android phone to test

Comment: What is the error

Comment: once I click the print button, the app crashes

Comment: What is the error that is written in the console though? Connect the phone to the computer and open up chrome remote devices and see.

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't log any error at all

Comment: i've the same issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, simply add the printoptions like you rightfully said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to apply the printoptions with an document name.

```
Printer.print("<h2>This is just a sample!</h2>", { name: 'testdoc' })
```